# Loading an old boost::serialisation archive with different class layout

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have an old (boost::serialisation) archive, which was generated using:

```
class Data;
data = new Data();
ar & data;
```

Now the code has changed to:

```
class Header;
class Data;
header = new Header();
data = new Data();
ar & header;
ar & data;
```

So, my question: **how do I load the old archive with the new code?**  As far as I can tell, boost::serialisation doesn't allow archive versioning, and if I just try to load it, it'll give me an "input stream error", because it'll try to `ar & header;` on data that was saved with `ar & data;`.

EDIT: I'm aware of `BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(ns::Class, x)`, but this does not apply to archives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that there is no way to do it other than writing a conversion program for the old version archives.

However, now having the 'header' in there, in future, I can bump the version of that and use some logic in my loading function if I ever need to add more classes to the top level.

Answer (score 2):

Boost serialization [*does* allow versioning](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#versioning). Unfortunately you did not know this so you just broke backward compatibility by saving new archives with `ar & header` *without bumping the class version*.

The tutorial linked above explains it well. In your case, when you decided to add the `header`, you had to do it as follows:

```
class YourClass
{
    /* ... */

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        if(version > 0)
            ar & header;
        ar & data;
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(YourClass, 1)
```

You must bump the version of the class *each time* you change the serialization code, even if you add fields only at the end.

Comment: Edited question to clarify that I'm talking about classes rather than members.

Comment: @Tim: It does not change much, you should either save your own version at the beginning of the archive, or wrap the whole code in a separate class and proceed as above. Anyway since you didn't care about it a priori, you can't fix it now and make it magically work.

Comment: That's what the Header class is there for.  If it's not possible to do this, then I'll just have a write up an archive converting hack, and run that on any old archives.

Comment: @Tim: As I said: "*since you didn't care about it a priori, you can't fix it now and make it magically work.*" Just implement one of the above approaches, or scrap `boost::serialization`. I had enough problems with this library: [\[1\]](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5876) [\[2\]](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/5499).